# Attempts at backwards compatibility

Tags: packages, variable-definitions, contexts, compatibility, development

I have written a package in Mathematica 11, and I would like to provide some backwards compatibility to earlier versions. An example is the function `Echo`.

Currently I define `Echo` in the following way.

```
Quiet[System`Echo[x_] := (Print[x]; x);]
```

As far as I understand, this defines `Echo` for example in version 10 where it was not part of the core language, and in version 11 it does nothing.

This is fine when I'm working inside of `` Global` ``, but when I go into my package's `` Private` `` I then have problems. My package seems to try to access `` Private`Echo `` when I write just `Echo`, but I would like it to access `` System`Echo ``.

To me this seems like it should be the default behaviour; as far as I understand other core language functions such as `Print` are in `` Sytem` `` and so I think Mathematica should look inside of `` System` `` before looking inside of `` Private` ``, only it appears not to.

Can anybody explain to me why this doesn't work? 
And any suggestions for a solution would be great, thank you.

EDIT:

Here is some example code, which all sits in my package file.

```
Quiet[System`Echo[x_] := (Print[x]; x);]

BeginPackage["Example`"];
myfunc::usage = "";
Begin["`Private`"];

myfunc[x_] := Echo[x^2]

End[];
EndPackage[];
```

I would like to be able to access `Echo` both inside the package, and in a session where the package is loaded. In this current example, the call to `Echo` in the package accesses `` Private`Echo ``, which is not what I want.

EDIT2:
The above code works fine, thanks to Szalbocs for pointing out a missing backtick.

Comment: When do you define this `Echo`? Before or after you load your package?

Comment: To discuss the context where Echo is created, we would need to know what you are doing exactly (a complete minimal example, also pointing out the order of operations)

Comment: That should be ``Begin["`Private`"]`` and not ``Begin["Private`"]``.  I cannot reproduce the problem you claim.

Comment: Ohhhh.... I see. I'd been using ``Begin["Private`"]`` for quite a while. It works fine now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you just want backwards compatibility, there is no need to create any symbols in the System context.  It seems like a bad idea to do such things.  A package should create symbols only within its own context to avoid conflicts.  Imagine what would happen if two different packages tried to define `` System`Echo ``, each in their own and incompatible way?

---

I suggest you simply do

```
If[$VersionNumber >= 10.3,
  echo = Echo,
  echo[x_] := (Print[x]; x)
]
```

in the private section of the package, then use `echo`.  [This is what I personally do.](https://github.com/szhorvat/MaTeX/blob/master/MaTeX/MaTeX.m#L61)

If you insist on using `Echo` instead of `echo`, it is still not necessary to create symbols in the System context.  This will work:

```
If[$VersionNumber < 10.3,
  Echo[x_] := (Print[x]; x)
]
```

In 10.2 and earlier, `Echo` will live in the `` `Private` `` context of the package, but that won't affect how your package functions can use it.  (However, should someone else's package make the questionable decision to create `` System`Echo ``, this approach will fail.)

However, I think it is a much better idea to use a distinct name such as `echo`. There are several advantages:

- You can work around bugs in earlier versions (I had to do this on several occasions)
- You can not only add a missing function, but add *missing features* of a function without having to modify System context symbols.
- You can more easily achieve consistent behaviour between versions. Your Echo implementation is not exactly equivalent to the built-in `Echo`. Recreating a complex built-in function is often difficult. Instead, focus on an easy-to-implement subset of functionality.

#### Other tips to help with backwards compatibility

- Always, always test in the earliest version that you need to support.  I learned the hard way that there *will* be unexpected incompatibilities.
- Do not rely on the *Updated in...* line at the bottom of documentation pages.  Check for yourself when the change was introduced.  These version notes in the documentation are automatically generated based on when the *documentation page* was last changed, not based on when the function was last updated.
- Use the [Mathematica plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](http://wlplugin.halirutan.de/).  It allows setting a target version and will flag any functions that you are trying to use that are not available in that version.

  [image]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'd like to define `Echo` and not `echo`. I avoided using `$VersionNumber` because that way I don't have to check what version things were added in. I want this `Echo` to be accessible to a session with the package loaded and not just the package internally. I don't need to add it to ``System` ``, that was just what I thought made sense. ``Global` `` didn't work for me either. I have updated my question.